# How do I iterate a loop with time delays in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delay

So basically I'm trying to print the word "yo" 20 times with a 2 second time delay between each iteration. This is what I came up with which doesn't work

```
    var j = 0
    while(j < 20){
        print("yo")

        let seconds = 2.0
        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)//nanoseconds per seconds
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            j+=1
        }

    }
```

Who knows the right way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an NSTimer that repeats, track `j` much as you are now and invalidate the timer when you are done

Comment: Move `print("yo")` into `dispatch_after`? And take `j+=1` out of `dispatch_after`. Then you could calculate the time to dispatch each loop (eg. j * seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It creates 20 print yo closures at one time instead of serially delaying between each one.

```
let delay = 2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
(1...20).map {
  iteration in
  let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(iteration)))
  dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print("yo")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this function

```
func repeatedPrint(count: Int, withDelay delay: Double)
{
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        if count < 1 {return}
        print("yo")
        self.repeatedPrint(count - 1, delay: delay)
    }
}

repeatedPrint(20, delay: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close. You need to put the print statement inside the dispatch_after:

```
var j: UInt64 = 0
let seconds: UInt64 = 1
while(j < 10)
{
  let delay = seconds *  j * NSEC_PER_SEC //nanoseconds per seconds
  let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
  dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
  {
    print("yo")
  }

  j += 1
}
print("Should start \"yo'ing\" soon")
```

Also your math was off. the delay value to dispatch_time is a UInt64, not a double.

Note that the code above probably won't work in a playground, since as soon as the main code path finishes, it terminates.

Comment: @NguzziMan, you should accept one of the answers you've been given if they solve your problem. (Click the check-mark.)